# How to add "Additional Options" to product while add to cart using GraphQL

Tags: magento2, addtocart, graphql, additional-options

I am using magento's default add to cart graphql to add product in cart.

```
mutation {
  addSimpleProductsToCart(input: 
    {cart_id: "aIvRj9FfJvQr3qcAECmFfZlVbxcwQ1G6", 
      cart_items: 
      [{
        data: 
        {quantity: 1, 
          sku: "t-shirt",
        },
      }]
    }) 
  {
    cart {
      items {
        id
        product {
          sku
          stock_status
        }
        ... on SimpleCartItem {
          customizable_options {
            customizable_option_uid
            label
            values {
              customizable_option_value_uid
              value
            }
          }
        }
        quantity
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This successfully adds the product to my cart.

Now, I want to add additional options with my cart item. I have tried using

```
customizable_options: [{id: 1, value_string: "1"}],
```

But this only works for Product's existing custom options.

Is there anyway I can add additional options to my cart item using graphql?

Comment: did you get any solution for this?